# Hide ID in web browser source debugging tool

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, model-view-controller

```
var obj = { ID: $("#ID").val(), Name: $("#Name").val(), Address: $("#Address").val() };
        $.ajax({
```

My question is how to hide the ID in Sources(Web browser debugging tool), because I don't feel like its safe to expose the ID in Source debugging tool.
I am passing the objects above to MVC Action using ajax , once it is received, there will be an id value in parameter, but in Sources(NO ID), so is there any magic needed here? Any approach will do.

Comment: To answer your question, no, it's not safe. What you should do, is store the ID as a session variable if it's a crucial data component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is never safe to parse crucial data components in client side environments. What you could do, is handle such logic server side through [sessions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx) and access them in the relevant file when needed, without parsing it through any JavaScript or similar.